# .wmv Media player in java

Tags: java, api, applet, media

I am looking into creating a java applet/swing that can play .wmv video files, What are some of the most current/ useful API in doing so? Thank you.

Comment: You won't get anything close to 'current' with Java applets, unfortunately. They are pretty much deprecated technology.

Comment: @GoranJovic  Applets have had improvements and updates in versions 1.4, 1.5 & 1.6.  In no way are they 'pretty much deprecated'.